# Display a text at the center of a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a Drag and Drop feature to my Dynamics CRM environment. In the below picture, the first one is the default Dynamics CRM subgrid that has a nice Icon and text.

The second grid is the one that I'm making. I want to put a text and same icon like the default one has. How could i achieve this? I just want to put the icon and text.

[image: Drag and Drop grid]

This is how i create my divs and put text in it.

```
   //Drop-zone placeholder text
    if (this.directionCode) {
        debugger;
        this._divNoRecordsContainerGrid = document.createElement("div");
        this._divNoRecordsContainerGrid.className = "cc-grid-noRecords-Container";
        this._divNoRecordsContainerGrid.id = "gridNoRecords";

        this._divNoRecordsContainer = document.createElement("div");
        this._divNoRecordsContainer.className = "flexbox";
        this._divNoRecordsContainer.setAttribute("role", "presentation");
        this._divNoRecordsContainer.title = "No data available";

        this._spanNoRecordsIcon = document.createElement("span");
        this._spanNoRecordsIcon.className = "symbolFont InsertKbArticle-symbol";
        this._spanNoRecordsIcon.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

        this._spanNoRecordsText = document.createElement("span");
        this._spanNoRecordsText.innerHTML = "Drag and drop your attachments here";

        this._divNoRecordsContainer.appendChild(this._spanNoRecordsIcon);
        this._divNoRecordsContainer.appendChild(this._spanNoRecordsText);
        this._divNoRecordsContainerGrid.appendChild(this._divNoRecordsContainer);

        this._attachmentContainer.appendChild(this._divNoRecordsContainerGrid);
    }
```

And css class:

```
.cc-grid-noRecords-Container {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: flex;`.

`justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` center the values of the div and only work with `display: flex;`

The `flex-direction: column;` is for making the divs among each other.

Do not forget to give the div a height!

Here's an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20">
  <p>No data available</p>
</div>
```